# hook_cron_queue_info doesn't run

Tags: 7, queue

I am using hook_cron in my module to create a queue.  The queue will process a couple of non-drupal database tables and synch some data around (a process that can take close to 10 minutes).  I'm creating a single item (`createItem`) and don't need to pass anything to the function.  I'm passing null to `createItem` and I've also tried passing an StdClass object.

```
$queue = DrupalQueue::get("alltimesynch");
$queue->createItem(null);
```

However, `hook_cron_queue_info` never runs.  I know this because the watchdog function never adds the string to the log

```
function timesdb_cron_queue_info() {
  watchdog("timesdb","timesdb_cron_queue_info called");
  $queues['alltimesynch'] = array (
    'worker callback' => 'timesdb_import_alltime_start',
  );
}
function timesdb_import_alltime_start($null) {
  watchdog("timesdb","Starting alltime import");
  timesdb_import_alltime();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return $queues in your hook_cron_queue_info..

```
function timesdb_cron_queue_info() {
  watchdog("timesdb","timesdb_cron_queue_info called");
  $queues['alltimesynch'] = array (
    'worker callback' => 'timesdb_import_alltime_start',
  );
  return $queues;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. The blog I used to learn this process left that part out.